# Retrieve polygon attribute when positionning a point - openlayers / leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openlayers, client

Using a client-side webmapping library (openlayers3 or leaflet), I want my user to be able to add one marker on the map. I will then be able to retrieve long/lat coordinates.

From that, I want to know if it is located inside a polygon (from another layer) and retrieve polygon attributes. Is that possible ?

Comment: It is possible, for sure, try some online demo and we can help somehow. You can [fork a clean map](http://plnkr.co/edit/MpRpn2?p=preview) and work on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jonatas. For now I just wanted to know if that was possible and I would have been happy with a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible. With leafletjs you can use this Mapbox API: [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip)

Once you have captured the users clicked coordinates you can use them like in the example linked above:

```
var userCoords = ????
var gjLayer = L.geoJson(statesData);
var results = leafletPip.pointInLayer(userCoords, gjLayer);
```

This will give you an array of polygons that contain that point, along with all the polygons attributes.